# Solr - string vs strings

Tags: solr

What is the difference between solr's `string` and `strings`?

I want to store text which is not english. It is UTF-8 encoded Tamil string. I don't want that to be indexed. So I opted out text options. Which one should I use?

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between "string" and "strings" is; "string" is a single valued field and "strings" is a multivalued field. Their value type is the same: "StrField".

Comment: We have multivalued property. If we want, we can set that as a property of multivalued string field. Isn't?

Comment: Sure. You can modify the field definition to match your needs. These are just convenience definitions.